# Parsing JSON response in javascript returns duplicate rows when appended

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, symfony

i just returned a response from controller i am using symfony3 and parse it to an html table but the result is a duplicated rows below my code :

Controller :

```
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $RAW_QUERY = 'SELECT id,DO_Date,DL_Design,DL_Qte,DL_MontantHT,DL_MontantTTC FROM `facture_ligne` WHERE facture_id=:id';

            $statement = $em->getConnection()->prepare($RAW_QUERY);
            // Set parameters
            $statement->bindValue('id', $id);
            $statement->execute();

            $facture = $statement->fetchAll();

            $serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
            $reports = $serializer->serialize($facture,'json');
            return new Response($reports);
```

My script :

```
{% for fact in facture %}

                                    <script>

                                        ( function () {


      var z= new XMLHttpRequest();
      z.open("get","{{ path('Ajaxonify',{'id':fact.id}) }})",true);

                                            z.send()

z.onreadystatechange = function result () {
          var obj=z.responseText;
          if(obj!="")
          {
              json = JSON.parse(obj);

              var tr;
              for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                  tr = $('<tr/>');
                  tr.append("<td>" + json[i].id + "</td>");
                  tr.append("<td>" + json[i].DO_Date + "</td>");
                  tr.append("<td>" + json[i].DL_Design + "</td>");
                  tr.append("<td>" + json[i].DL_Qte + "</td>");
                  tr.append("<td>" + json[i].DL_MontantHT + "</td>");
                  tr.append("<td>" + json[i].DL_MontantTTC + "</td>");

                  $('#tb{{ fact.id  }}').append(tr);
              }
          }
      }
})();
```

And this is the result :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add check for `XMLHttpRequest.readyState`

```
z.onreadystatechange = function result () {
    if (z.readyState != 4) {
        return;
    }
    .... 
}
```

Comment: I m on mobile now i will try it tomorow in work thanks

Comment: Thanks it works fine . Now i understood the purpose behind checking if the request has reached the fourth state